# How can I concat the product name with its unit?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my query:

```
Branch::active()->ProductUnit()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

I need to concat the product `name` with its `unit`. Also I've a relation in the `product` model like this:

```
public function unit()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
}
```

And I want to make a **scope** in that model to handle that concoction:

```
public function scopeProductUnit(Builder $query)
{
    return $query-> ... ?
}
```

How should I write that scope and how to use it in the query?

Answer (score -1):

You can [append](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) your response. Add this to your product model

```
protected $appends = ['name_with_unit'];
```

Then use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to modify data

```
public function getNameWithUnitAttribute()
{
    return $this->name . $this->unit->name; // update by your column name
}
```